# "Cannot invoke ObserveForever on the background thread", doesn't matter if am I using Dispatchers.Main or Dispatchers.IO to launch the coroutine

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, mutablelivedata

## What I am trying to do

I made a weather application based on MVVM architecture in which I am fetching the device location using GPS and passing the location to a weather API service to get the Weather Reports, but because of the fact that the location may change and the user needs to fetch the weather again for new location, I wrapped the location in LiveData and observing it and passing it to the API service class.

In short I am launching a coroutine with GlobalScope inside the observeForever of LiveData

**WeatherNetworkAbstractionsImpl.kt**

```
class WeatherNetworkAbstractionsImpl(
    private val weatherApiService: WeatherApiService,
    private val context: Context
) : WeatherNetworkAbstractions {

    private val _downloadedWeather = MutableLiveData<WeatherResponse>()
    override val downloadedWeather: LiveData<WeatherResponse>
        get() = _downloadedWeather

    override suspend fun fetchWeather(location: LiveData<String>) {
        try {
            location.observeForever {
                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val fetchedWeather = weatherApiService.getWeather(it).await()
                    _downloadedWeather.postValue(fetchedWeather)
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e: NoConnectivityException){
            Log.e("Connectivity","No internet connection.",e)
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository.kt**

```
class RepositoryImpl(
    private val weatherDao: WeatherDataDao,
    private val weatherNetworkAbstractions: WeatherNetworkAbstractions,
    private val weatherLocationDao: WeatherLocationDao,
    private val recordMapperImpl: RecordMapperImpl,
    private val locationMapperImpl: LocationMapperImpl,
    private val locationProvider: LocationProvider
) : Repository {
    init {
        weatherNetworkAbstractions.downloadedWeather.observeForever {latestWeatherReports->
            persistLatestWeatherReports(latestWeatherReports, recordMapperImpl, locationMapperImpl)
        }
    }
}
```

## What my problem is

I am getting this error:

> Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread

even if I changed the  Dispatchers.IO to Dispatchers.Main but still getting the same error.

How can I resolve the issue? I am new to coroutines.

Comment: Could you change whatever is providing you with `location` to do something other than `LiveData` (e.g., a `Flow`)? Your error is because `fetchWeather()` itself is being called on a background thread.

Comment: You can use `callbackFlow` to convert location callback to a flow and collect the flow like `locationFlow.collect { ... }`

Comment: yeah you are righ, i am launching this under GloabalScope inside my repository, please refer to my repository code that i have just updated,

Comment: by callbackFlow did you mean i have to use RxJava, can you please give me an example for better understanding @Faith

Comment: You can do something like this `callbackFlow { val locationCallback = object : MyLocationCallback { ...} locationService.registerListener(locationCallback) awaitClose { locationService.unregisterListener(locationCallback) } } `. You can check it out from https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html

Comment: but fetching location is not a asynchronous task, actully user is manually changing the location and onChange of the location i am setting the new location using LiveData.postValue() method @Faith